# Copy system file to my bundle

Tags: iphone

with iphone SDK 4.0 i want to use some system sound files eg /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-0.caf
I was thinking it is best to have this in my own bundle but how to copy it to my bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file you drag into your project and add to your target (which should be default) will get copied into the application bundle when you build it. You may not have the legal right to distribute sound files that are part of OS X though.

Comment: but i can't drag the file above,  is there a way to programatically copy